# Twilio sms response with name stored in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, twilio

Im trying to make an sms responder that sends the text to email with the senders name queried from a mysql database, I always get Unkown Sender even when i text with a number that is stored in the database .

The php script receives the senders phone number, my database has a "drivers database with their Name and Telephone number, I want to be able to identify the sender of the text message by running a lookup array of telephone numbers stored in mysql database.

```html
<?php
/**
 * This section ensures that Twilio gets a response.
 */
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
echo '<Response></Response>'; //Place the desired response (if any) here
 
 
 // create connection 
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") 
or die("Couldn't make connection."); 

// select database 
$db = mysql_select_db("database", $connection) 
or die("Couldn't select database."); 


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM driver");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)); 
 
   // make an associative array of senders name stored in the database, indexed by phone number
    $people = array(
        $row["telephone"]=>$row["name"],
        
    );
 
    // if the sender is known, then greet them by name
    // otherwise, consider them unknown
    if(!$name = $people[$_REQUEST['From']]) {
        $name = "Unknown Sender";
    }
 

 
/**
 * This section actually sends the email.
 */
$to      = "sms@domain.com"; // Your email address
$subject = "Text message from $name ";
$message = "You received an sms message from $name with number {$_REQUEST['From']}.




MESSAGE:

 {$_REQUEST['Body']}";
$headers = "From: sms@domain.com"; // Who should it come from?
 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Comment: Can you let us know what the problem your encountering is?  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I revised my description. The code always results as "unknown user".